# How to raise different messages when the ValidationError is caused due to max_length limit and min_length limit in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-validation

I want to create a model in Django where I could introduce character values for a given field (task), with min_limit=1 and max_limit=255. The code would be something like this in the **models.py file:**

```
class ListModel(models.Model):
    task = models.CharField(max_length= 255, validators = [MinLengthValidator(1), MaxLengthValidator(255)])
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class ListForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ListModel
        fields = ["task", "status"]
```

Now, if the form is not valid I want to show different messages depending on whether it is invalid because of max_length>255 or because of min_length<1, the code would be something like this in the **views.py file:**

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ListForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            #some code

        else:
            if max_length > 255:
                messages.info(request, ('Maximum length limit: 255 characters!'))
            else:
                messages.info(request, ('No Task added!')
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        #some code
```

> `class MaxLengthValidator(limit_value, message=None)`¶
> Raises a ValidationError with a code of 'max_length' if the length of
> value is greater than limit_value, which may be a callable.

In the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/validators/#maxlengthvalidator) it's mentioned that max_length is callable but I am not sure how to call it in views.py. What could I do to show different messages when max_length>255 and when min_length<1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to navigate the most part of the code yourself.
To access the form errors in `views.py`

```
if form.is_valid():
    #some code
else:
    print(form.errors.get("task"))
```

`form.errors()` will return html
you can then manipulate your code however you want

In my case, I used beautifulSoup to parse the html, clean it and checked with conditionals

Comment: I meant to say "```form.errors``` will return ......." instead of "```form.errors()``` will return ......."

Comment: Thank you so much for letting me know about `form.errors` as I am new to Django. In my case using conditionals on `form.errors.get("task").as_text()` solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I've got two solutions for my problem

**Solution 1 (this is what I was looking for):**

```
if form.is_valid():
    #some code
else:
    task = request.POST.get("task")
    if len(task) > 255:
        messages.info(request, f"Maximum length limit is 255 characters, but your task has {len(task)} characters")
    elif len(task) < 1:
        messages.info(request, ('No Task added!')
    return redirect('index')
```

**Solution 2:**

in **views.py** code looks something like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    #some code
else:
    messages.info(request,(form.errors.get("item").as_text()))
    return redirect('index')
```

and in **forms.py** or **models.py** wherever your Form class is, the code will be:

```
class ListForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ListModel
        fields = ["task", "status"]

        error_messages = {
            'task': {
                "required": ("No task added!"),
                'max_length': ("Maximum length limit: 255 characters!"),
            },
        }
```

**The advantage of solution 1 over solution 2** is that we can display the number of characters the user has typed even when the form.is_valid() is False, which I am not sure can be done in the second method, but do let me know in the comments if it can be done using the second method as well :)